# SQL Update - Only if there are no constraints

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query like this,

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
           WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Enrollment' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'nosuchfield')
BEGIN
    UPDATE dbo.Enrollment 
    SET nosuchfield='666'
END
```

I want to update it only when there is no key constraints on it (primary key, foreign key constraints).

Comment: On what, the table, the column? Just Foreign Key constraints? What about `CHECK` constraints? Do you *really* want to update the value of every row?

Comment: I want to go into the update only if 'nosuchfield' column in 'Enrollment' Table is not a primary or foreign key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This uses the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` objects, rather than the `sys` objects (the latter are recommended, but I had something to hand for the former), that should get what you are after:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
               FROM  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS ISC 
                     JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS TC ON ISC.TABLE_SCHEMA = TC.TABLE_SCHEMA
                                                                 AND ISC.TABLE_NAME = TC.TABLE_NAME
                     JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE KCU ON TC.TABLE_SCHEMA = KCU.TABLE_SCHEMA
                                                                 AND TC.TABLE_NAME = KCU.TABLE_NAME
                                                                 AND TC.CONSTRAINT_NAME = KCU.CONSTRAINT_NAME
                                                                 AND ISC.COLUMN_NAME = KCU.COLUMN_NAME
               WHERE ISC.TABLE_SCHEMA = N'dbo' --TABLE_SCHEMA is not always accurate
                 AND ISC.TABLE_NAME = N'Enrollment'
                 AND ISC.COLUMN_NAME = N'nosuchfield'
                 AND TC.CONSTRAINT_TYPE IN ('PRIMARY KEY','FOREIGN KEY'))
    UPDATE dbo.Enrollment
    SET nosuchfield = '666';
```